# QT GUI crashes upon creating C++ std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

Why does my GUI crash after i create a new thread with std::thread? The only output I receive is:

> Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
>   Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

Just those 2 lines and a message from windows that the application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton;
    button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    connect(button, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(buttonSignal()));
    layout->addWidget(button);
    centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);
}

void foo(){
    //want to do stuff in here
}

void MainWindow::buttonSignal(){
    std::thread thread (foo);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: I think there is some context missing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `thread` object is local in `MainWindow::buttonSignal` and is not joined prior to destruction, which is a runtime error that leads to [`std::terminate` being called](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

You can make your thread object a member of `MainWindow` class, and then initiate the thread in `MainWindow::buttonSignal`

```
void MainWindow::buttonSignal(){
    thread = std::thread(foo);
}
```

This will create a temporary `std::thread`, which will be moved using [move assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D).

Don't forget to explicitly join the thread before destruction:

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    if (thread.joinable())
        thread.join();
}
```

And, of course, don't forget to properly synchronize all communication between threads.

Comment: Oh, yeah that makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

since the `thread` variable is destroyed after `buttonSignal` method exits, you should detach thread from the variable.

```
void MainWindow::buttonSignal(){
    std::thread thread (foo);
    thread.detach();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using std::async with a lambda function to do minor tasks in a separate thread. You could then have a std::future class member initialized from that to get results and notification. 
Alternatively there is QFuture and QFutureWatcher from the QtConcurrent framework.